# How can I use 'Check' statement to validate field value in mysql?

Tags: mysql, constraints

How can I use 'Check' statement to validate field value  in mysql?

look at this [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html), in the manual didn't discussed about **check** keyword

In **MySql Workbench** and **Navicat for mysql**, there is not exists any options to set constraints or check.

Comment: You can create a view and try inserting data in a view instead of table. The view constraints are enforced. This is a workaround though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not enforce CHECK constraints. It parses the check constraint clause, but silently ignores it. You'd have to use a trigger to validate data.